# How to Change code to read linq result already written via IDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework

Working on already build application code and now to work on similar line but with Entity framework(oracle). Facing issue to change the below code

```
// Already Written Code

private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ExecuteReader1(
    IDbCommand command, List<IMapper<T>> mappers)
{
    var listOfList = new List<IEnumerable<T>>();

    //Here i have written code to fetch the data using LINQ (Entity Framework with Oracle)

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
    {
        foreach (var mapper in mappers)
        {
            List<T> list;
            ReadResultset(reader, mapper, out list);
            listOfList.Add(list);

            if (!reader.NextResult())
                break;
        }
    }

    return listOfList;
}

private static void ReadResultset(IDataReader reader, IMapper<T> mapper, out List<T> list)
{
    list = new List<T>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var item = new T();
        mapper.Map(reader, item);
        list.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Question: How to change the above code since now result will be in Linq. Please tell the best practice

Comment: What do yo mean 'the result will be in Linq'?

Comment: now data would be fetched from linq, just above "Execute Reader" line.